# submit a form with an image, AND in a popup window

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popupwindow

This is my code:

```
<form id="email" action="email_send.php" method="POST" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="slastupdate" value="<?php echo $row['slastupdate']; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="saldo" size="25" value="<?php echo $row['saldo']; ?>" />

<!--This part of the code gets the form submitted by clicking on an image--!>
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('email').submit(); return false;" target="_blank">
<img src="../img/enviar-mail.png"></a>
</form>
```

I have located this at the end of the body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function target_popup(form) {
        window.open('', 'formpopup', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=300,left = 312,top = 234');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
    }
</script>
```

So, basically, this works just fine to submit the form by clicking on an image and it would be very really awesome to keep it that way. But the target_popup(this) code should open a popup window after the form is submited, but instead the form gets sent to the same window.
Sorry for the bad english (Hope to be wrong about that), I'm not native and I've possibly made some mistakes :P

Answer (score 1):

you should use **_blank** as the window name.... please replace this line:

```
window.open('', 'formpopup', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=300,left = 312,top = 234');
```

with this line:

```
 window.open('', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=300,left = 312,top = 234');
```

Comment: That's not working, not even changing the form as you said and also `form.target = 'formpopup';` with `form.target = '_blank';` still target appears to be in the same window.

Comment: replace the order... place form.target = '_blank'; before openning a new window

Comment: After some research, I found [jQuery's submit() method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). In the docs they explain how to submit a form with a `.click()` function that can be triggered when clicking on a `div`, for ej.Yet I couldn't get this to work on my code. I gave up because I reallised I can make an `input type="submit"` look exactly like an `a` tag or like anything I want with some CSS. Thanks for the help, anyways :)

Comment: Ps: The code I posted originally works perfectly when the form gets posted by a `<button>` tag. All credits for that code to [electrictoolbox](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/post-form-popup-window-javascript-jquery/). In case someone runs with a similar problem, in [this page you can learn more about customizing buttons with CSS](http://rickyrosario.com/blog/using-the-html-button-element-in-place-of-input-type-submit/)